# How much does beer attenuate light?

Tags: visible-light

So earlier I was finishing off a beer, and couldn't help but contemplate this: [Could I look at the sun through a brown or green beer bottle with out damaging my eyes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/351772/could-i-look-at-the-sun-through-a-brown-or-green-beer-bottle-with-out-damaging-m) failed question. And I looked at the light on my ceiling and looked at it through the bottle, and estimated the bottle was dimming it by roughly half.. and thought to myself aha now I know I'd need a lot more than two beer bottles to look at the sun... but then I was drinking a different beer and looked at the light actually through the beer (and glass) and I couldn't even make out the light because so much light was blocked. Hopefully you understand the question now. lol

Comment: I guess mostly I just want someone to do some work with the relevant equations so I can understand the broader questions better..

Comment: You can read [Light Absorption by Various Beer Bottle Glass](http://www.brewangels.com/Beerformation/bbrskunking.pdf).  You'll also get an understanding of why colored glass is used for beers (apart from marketing).

Comment: You are describing a well known non-linear absorption effect based on the total amount of beer. The first 6-pack doesn't stop much light, but soon after that light stops rather abruptly.

Comment: @safesphere  Do you have any reference for this non-linear effect? Or are you referring to the Beer-Lambert Law?

Comment: @user273872 Yes it is amazing how much more satisfying a page of mysterious equations can be, even if you don't understand them and the result has no practical value, than a simple experiment which anyone can do and tells you exactly what you want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physics is described by [Beer-Lambert's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law), but what you are looking for is probably called *Lambert's beer law*.

Unfortunately, the absorption coeff of beer strongly depends on which beer you are drinking: There are dark beers, which absorb light efficiently, and almost transparent beers, which do not. The same is true for the glasses of the bottles (see link by StephenG). Therefore, if your aim is to **switch off the lights by using a beer**, you best chances are

1. to hit the light by throwing the bottle
2. drinking so much, that the beer switches off *your* lights.

Comment: "hit the light by throwing the bottle".  Love it. :-)